# Auto-Numbering Script on Mouse Click

Tags: pdf, macros, autohotkey

I found this script for (AHK), while looking for a solution regarding to the topic.

```
F11:: Number = 0
F12:: MacroOn := ! MacroOn

~$LButton::
   KeyWait LButton
   If MacroOn
   {
      If ! Number
      {
         InputBox Number, AutoNumbering
            , Enter starting number: , , , , , , , , 1
         If ( ErrorLevel or ! Number ) ; canceled
            Return
      }
      SendInput {Click}%Number%
      ++Number
   }
Return
```

The code works fine but is there a way to make my Right-Mouseclick output the same number as before without adding 1 to it?

I have no experience in programming, so excuse me if its a simple task.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Replace `LButton` by `RButton` and remove the line `++Number`. For sending right clicks, replace `SendInput {Click}%Number%` by `SendInput {Click right}%Number%`